# table initialization list take to int, in user defined class

Tags: c++, list, class, constructor, user-defined

this is my short code

```
class A {
public:
    int x,y;
    A(int a=0, int b=0) {
        x=a;y=b;
    }
};
int main() {
    A t[2] = {9,3};
    cout << t[0].x << " " << t[0].y << endl;
    cout << t[1].x << " " << t[1].y << endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
9 0
3 0
```

When i comment my constructor:

```
9 3
0 0
```

My question is: why is that? I've tried to overload everything i could figure, that means:copy constructor, constructor with one,two parameters, (coma,equality,[]) operators, but I don't know what compiler generates that it can take 2 integers in one constructor and assign them to x,y. I even tried to overflow numbers in brackets{}, by putting {99999999999999999999,3} to see what compiler will yell but it says it can't convert const int because of overflow, so I believe it must be conversion, but how?

Comment: What compiler do you use? Is C++11 support enabled?

Comment: Does it matter? If yes, please consider both situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're implicitly converting `9`, and `3` to `A`.

A small test will prove this:

```
class A {
public:
    int x,y;
    explicit A(int a=0, int b=0) {
        x=a;y=b;
    }
};
```

This will yield a compilation error.

That means that your code translates to:

```
A t[2] = {A(9),A(3)};
```

Since commenting out the conversion constructor (let's call it that, although I'm not sure it is), it will no longer be able to convert `int` to `A`.

The second snippet will only initialize the first element.

EDIT: To clarify, try the following test:

```
int x[10] = {1,1,1};
```

This will only initialize the first 3 elements of the array.

Also, without the conversion constructor, try the following:

```
A t[4] = {1,1,2,2};
```

The first 2 `A`'s will be initialized.

Comment: @aragornsql np, hope it explains the behavior.

Comment: I thought about that, but how it is possible to cast 2 ints to 1 A. Te casting template is: T::operator R() const; ?

Comment: @aragornsql it's not casting, it's called conversion. And it uses a conversion constructor. Defining a constructor A(int) without the keyword `explicit` will tell the compiler that it can implicitly convert an `int` to an `A` if required. Google for conversion constructor.

Comment: Ok, I know what is conversion constructor it's all ok. Excuse me but I didn't make it clear. I don't know why without declaring any constructor, program creates object which consist of 2 int numebrs given in brackets {9,3}. I mean I complitely understand that when I have my constructor {9,3} means {(A)9, (A) 3}, but what I want is that first object to take both numbers, for that I need to use syntax like this {{9,3}} like passing two 2dim table. Without my contructor I don't need that syntax. I hope now you understand my inquisitiveness

Comment: @aragornsql Because that's the way this type of initialization works. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Again, thx but I get this "int x[10] ={1,1,1}". Ok let me ask it in different way. What should I overload (, add whatever) so that line "A t[2] = {9,3}" will create t[0].x=9,t[0].y=3, t[0].x=0,t[0].y=0. Let's point that I don't want compiler to anything for me, I want to be master of all constructors,conversions etc.

Comment: My mistake should be: t[0].x=9,t[0].y=3, t[1].x=0,t[1].y=0

Comment: @aragornsql a default constructor and - A t[2] = {A(9,3)}; I'm not sure you can achieve this with the exact syntax you have for initialization.

Comment: Oh, Luchian Grigore, that exactly what I want to know, whether it is possible with exact syntax, if not why compiler can do it, or sth more about this problem

Comment: @aragornsql while looking about in dissasembly (without optimizations), I can say that the compiler is directly copying the integers inside A[0]. No default constructor is called. So when you create a constructor, it will first try to match that (if it's a conversion constructor).

Comment: hm, you mean that it passes them to the object of class and assign without calling any additional procedures? It is even possible? :P

Comment: ofc I mean it is possible to write in main t[0].x = 4; But it is strange that compiler do it for all member fields

Comment: @aragornsql apparently that's what it does. Not sure if strange, I'm pretty sure it's some legacy functionality from c, where you could define structures and initialize them directly with {}.

Comment: @Luchain I said strange - because I've never seen sth like this. Ok, thanks for you help and time.